# How to say "My wife and I did something, then our friends and we [wife and I] did something else" correctly?

Tags: grammar

Which is best?

"My wife and I just got back from the beach. Before that, her sister and we visited Grandma".

vs.

"My wife and I just got back from the beach. Before that, her sister, she, and I visited Grandma".

vs.

"My wife and I just got back from the beach. Before that, her sister, my wife, and I visited Grandma".

Comment: I know it's usual to put 'I' at the end, but in this case I think it would be more natural to say 'we and her sister'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes where it is the first person plural it is "We and the Smiths went for a walk". If however the personnel are the direct objects, then it becomes "She prepared dinner for the Smiths and us".

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 might be technically okay, but it sounds awful.  Two is better, but it's a little ambiguous who "she" is, especially since you put the 'she' after naming a different woman.

The third option is better, but again, "her sister" is a little ambiguous when it comes before "my wife".  Better to put it after.

You can also avoid the whole problem by slightly rearranging the elements:

> My wife and I just got back from the beach.  Before that we visited
>   Grandma with my wife's sister.